# Pausing a ffmpeg screen capture?

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-capture

I have a script to record my screen using `ffmpeg`:

`ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast video.mkv`

I tried using `pkill -STOP ffmpeg` to pause the recording and `pkill -CONT ffmpeg` to resume it. The command seems to work correctly, pausing the recording process and later resuming it. However on playback, instead of instantly cutting to when I resumed `ffmpeg`, the video freezes for the duration I pause `ffmpeg`. Is there a way I can prevent the video from freezing, and instantly cut to when I resume recording? (I can upload a sample clip if that would help clarify something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the setpts filter to make timestamps continuous.

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vf setpts=N/FR/TB -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast video.mkv
```

Comment: Please highlight what was changed.